# How do I create an azure event grid system-topic using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm looking for the terraform equivalent to "[az eventgrid system-topic create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/eventgrid/eventgrid/system-topic?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-eventgrid-az-eventgrid-system-topic-create)" to create a system-topic to route messages from an IoT hub to the event grid. Neither azurerm_iothub not azurerm_eventgrid modules seem to provide such functionality. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today [terraform-provider-azurerm v2.32.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v2.32.0) has been released which added support for creating event grid system topics. See [this issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8293) for details. Thanks to everyone working on this feature.